# Raw photography with smartphone

Tags: camera, xiaomi

A few days ago, I bought a Xiaomi Mi 11i phone and I want to take pictures of the night sky with this phone. The main camera of this phone is 108 megapixels, but you probably know that you can not access all of these 108 megapixels raw and you only have access to 12 megapixels of that 108 megapixels camera raw. I want to have 100% raw images from the camera of this phone with a resolution of 108 megapixels.

I tried normal Android software such as Proshot, Procam, etc., but none of them can't give a 108-megapixel raw output and I was not allowed to expose it for more than 1 second.

Do you know any software that can be used to access all the capabilities of the sensor 100% raw and without restrictions?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/829342-astrophotography-with-smartphone-please-help/ (just in case it's answered there)

Comment: check out gcam mods for your device

Comment: Use case seems similar to [Script to interact with camera and take RAW pictures for astrophotography](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242435/3573)